# How to optimize this Tkinter "MS Paint"-like program?

Tags: python, optimization, tkinter, paint

I've been working for a bit on a Tkinter "Paint"-like program and I'm having issues with the performance. I had to set a 200ms delay to redraw because it can't really run without it. It has to use this grid system so that I can easily send it to the back-end.

It runs fine the first stroke or two but after, it uses a ton of CPU cycles and it is just unusable.

Could y'all work your magic and show me how to improve it, please?

I removed most of the useless stuff :

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, NW, NE, N

fen = Tk()
fen.geometry("1380x740")
fen.title("Dessine moi un mouton !")

c_width = 800
c_height = 600
couleur = "red"
epaisseur= 10

sdessin = Canvas(width = c_width, height = c_height, bg ='white')

board = []
for i in range(0, c_width, 10):
    board.append(["white" for j in range(0, c_height, 10)])

#board[4][7] = "red"

def pix_to_units(x, y):
    if x > 10 and y > 10:
        i = int(str(x)[:-1])
        j = int(str(y)[:-1])
        return i-1,j-1
    else:
        return 0, 0

def afficher_dessin(): #display board
    for i in range(len(board)):
        b = board[i]
        for j in range(len(b)):
            if b[j] != sdessin["background"]:
                sdessin.create_rectangle(i*10, j*10,i*10+10, j*10+10, fill = b[j], outline = b[j])

def draw():
    afficher_dessin()
    fen.after(200, draw)

def interaction(coords):
    i, j = pix_to_units(coords.x, coords.y)
    board[i][j] = couleur


sdessin.bind("<B1-Motion>", interaction)

sdessin.grid(row =2, column =2, sticky=N)

draw()
fen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think asking us to improve code is a bit too broad for stackoverflow. That being said, you create a very large number of objects on each iteration and you never destroy any items. That's definitely a problem.

Comment: Which objects should I delete and how ? Thanks for the swift response! I'm new to python but used to a more garbage collected language : java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created new rectangle items in each update, and it is the cause of CPU high usage and not necessary.  Just create the rectangle items once and update their color inside `iteraction()` function and no need to use `after()` to update the board.

Below is a simplified code based on yours:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, NW, NE, N

fen = Tk()
fen.geometry("1380x740")
fen.title("Dessine moi un mouton !")

c_width = 800
c_height = 600
couleur = "red"
epaisseur= 10

sdessin = Canvas(width = c_width, height = c_height, bg ='white')

rows, cols = c_height//10, c_width//10
# create the board
board = [['white' for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
# draw the board
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        x, y = col*10, row*10
        sdessin.create_rectangle(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill=board[row][col], outline='',
                                 tag='%d:%d'%(row,col))  # tag used for updating color later

def pix_to_units(x, y):
    return y//10, x//10   # row, col

def interaction(event):
    row, col = pix_to_units(event.x, event.y)
    board[row][col] = couleur
    tag = '%d:%d' % (row, col)
    sdessin.itemconfig(tag, fill=couleur)

sdessin.bind("<B1-Motion>", interaction)
sdessin.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=N)

fen.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! You just saved my day!